# Как заблокировать системное меню?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать кнопки в верхнем правом углу (красный крестик, свернуть...) недоступными в программе? Ок. Я знаю есть такое свойство, чтобы заболкировать верхние значки - крестики и т.д. Что это за свойство?

Comment: Вы не могли бы делать чуть более содержательные заголовки у своих вопросов?

Answer (score 2):

Все проще некуда.
Например:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 SysMenu: HMenu;
begin
 SysMenu:=GetSystemMenu(Handle, False);
 Windows.EnableMenuItem(SysMenu ,SC_CLOSE, MF_DISABLED Or MF_GRAYED);
end;
```

А так это все в FAQ написано, да и пример полным полно.

Comment: а чтобы просвечивание снялось MF_GRAYED в стандарт что там

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите Delphi Help: свойство BorderIcons у TCustomForm.

Answer (score -1):

Можно средствами WinAPI:

```
deletemenu(getsystemmenu(form1.Handle,false),SC_CLOSE,MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

Данная функция удаляет определенные компонент оконного меню( хэндл меню получается первым параметром ), второй параметр - что блокируем. Третий параметр - тип команды.